# AWS RDS MySQL fetching not being completed

Tags: mysql, amazon-web-services, fetch, amazon-rds

I am writing queries off tables in my AWS RDS MySQL server and I can't get the query to complete the fetching. The duration of the query is 5.328 seconds but then fetching just doesn't end. I have Left Joined a sub query. When I run the sub separately it runs very quick and almost has no fetch time. When I run the main query it works great. The main query does have about 97,000 rows. I'm new to AWS RDS Servers and wonder if there is a parameter adjustment I need to be made? I feel as if the query is pretty simple.

We are in the middle of switching from BigQuery and BigQuery runs it just fine with the same data and same query.

Any ideas of what I can do to get it to fetch and speed up the fetching?

I've tried indexing and changing buffer pool size but still no luck

```
FROM
    project__c P
    LEFT JOIN contact C ON C.id = P.salesperson__c
    LEFT JOIN account A ON A.id = P.sales_team_account_at_sale__c
    LEFT JOIN contact S ON S.id = P.rep_contact__c
    LEFT JOIN (
        SELECT
            U.name,
            C.rep_id__c EE_Code
        FROM
        user U
            LEFT JOIN profile P ON P.id = U.profileid
            LEFT JOIN contact C ON C.email = U.email
        WHERE
            (P.name LIKE "%Inside%"OR P.name LIKE "%rep%")
            AND C.active__c = TRUE
            AND C.rep_id__c IS NOT NULL
            AND C.recordtypeid = "############"
    ) LC ON LC.name = P.is_rep_formula__c
```

Comment: MySQL doesn't add indexes for subqueries. Try creating a temporary table with the subquery results, index it, and then join with that.

Comment: Also, use `INNER JOIN` unless you really need to get the non-matching rows. `LEFT JOIN` is generally slower.

Answer (score 0):

You can analyze the query by adding EXPLAIN [your query] and running that to see what indexes are being used and how many rows are examined for each joined table.  It might be joining a lot more rows than you expect.

You can try:

SELECT SQL_CALC_FOUND_ROWS [your query] limit 1;

If the problem is in sending too much data (i.e. more rows than you think it's trying to return), this will return quickly. It would prove that the problem does lie in sending the data, not in the query stage.  If this is what you find, run the following next:

select FOUND_ROWS();

This will tell you how many total rows matched your query.   If it's bigger than you expect, your joins are wrong in some way.   The explain analyzer mentioned above should provide some insight.  While the outer query has 97000 rows, each of those rows could join with more than one row from the subquery.   This can happen if you expect the left side of the join to always have a value, but find out there are rows in which it is empty/null. This can lead to a full cross join where every row from the left joins with every row on the right.

If the limit 1 query also hangs, the problem is in the query itself.   Again, the explain analyzer should tell you where the problem lies.  Most likely it's a missing index causing very slow scans of tables instead of fast lookups in both tables joins and where clauses.

The inner query might be fine/fast on its own.  When you join with another query, if not indexed/joined properly, it could lead to a result set and/or query time many times larger.

If missing indices with derived tables is the problem, read up on how mysql can optimize via different settings by visiting https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/derived-table-optimization.html

As seen in a comment to your question, creating a temp table and joining directly gives you control instead of relying on/hoping mysql to optimize your query in a way that uses fast indices.

I'm not versed in BigQuery, but unless it's running the same core mysql engine under the hood, it's not really a good comparison.

Why all the left joins.  Your subquery seems to be targeted to a small set of results, yet you still want to get 90k+ rows?  If you are using this query to render any sort of list in a web application, apply reasonable limits and pagination.